# Run Code from Script

Tags: python, bash

I feel this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to get this.

How do I create a shell script that takes the python script in a subdirectory and runs it.

So, for the following directory

```
├── shell_command.sh  
├── code_sub_directory  
│   ├── python_code_1.py  
│   └── python_code_2.py  
├── input_data  
    └── data.txt
```

I'm trying to create a script (called `shell_command.sh`) that runs `python_code_1.py` and `python_code_2.py` from the subdirectory `code_sub_directory`.

Here is the script that I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py
```

Which gives the error:

```
./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout
```

Comment: you don't run a python script using './', that syntax is for .sh files. Python script are run simply using 'python <filename>'

Comment: @AjayGupta: Not entirely true. Provided the Python script is set as executable and it has the correct shebang line, then that syntax should work.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question so that it changes completely and seems to be a different question...

Comment: Ah - apologies. Is is best to repost?

Comment: yeah, if it's different then it deserves a dedicated post...

Comment: Thanks and apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 4):

change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`. It's a shell script not python script.

Your *shell_command.sh* should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py
```

Comment: Thanks @Jahid. I did that and got the error "/usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
logout"

Comment: @hoof_hearted did you chmod+x the .py  file? python files are not automatically executable so unless you chmod +x the .py `./` will not work

Comment: @Jahid Now my code reads "#!/usr/bin/bash

./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py

#killall Terminal
"

Comment: @hoof_hearted, it's not `#!/usr/bin/bash`, it's `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Pardaic Cunningham Yes. I did that originally. Do I need to do it every time I edit the script?

Comment: @Jahid Thanks. But then I'm getting this error, which I was also getting before       "line 3: ./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py: No such file or directory
logout

[Process completed]"

Comment: @hoof_hearted, then you need to pass the full path to the file

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham . Thanks. I'll give that a try

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham. Is it not possible to run from the current folder. For example, if I send the file to another person, will the file path not change?

Comment: @hoof_hearted it is possible to run it from the current folder as long as you don't get the path incorrect. running any script from another folder has a general catch. If that other script look for any file with relative path it won't find it because the current dir is not the dir of the script unless you have changed it somehow.

Comment: @hoof_hearted when you are running the .sh script make sure you are running it from the scripts directory i.e the terminal should be cd'ed to that directory. then you can use `./path/pythonscript.py`

Comment: @Jahid Thanks. I get that but don't know how to deal with that? This, however, may be a topic for another post

Answer (score 3):

It is important that which ever script you are writing, you should change the shebang line accordingly

For Example:

```
Shell Script - #! /bin/bash
Python Script - #! /usr/bin/python
Perl Script - #! /usr/bin/perl
etc.
```

If you have multiple version of python for example. 
You need to use the value returned by `which python` command, after `#!`

The shebang should be the first line because it is interpreted by the kernel, which looks at the two bytes at the start of an executable file. If these are `#!` the rest of the line is interpreted as the executable to run and with the script file available to that program.

Comment: Should use     #!/bin/bash because it's a shell script, even though it's calling a python script?

Comment: The Script is a shell script So It can never be a python shebang line.

Comment: @hoof_hearted: Your *shell script* should have `#!/bin/bash` and your *python script* should have `#!/usr/bin/python`. The shebang line tells the OS what interpreter to use for the code that follows, which for the shell script is bash and for the python script is python.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into problems if you don't specify full paths for your scripts. Not always, but it's good to know.

**Without full paths:**

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Running Script without full paths"
./code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py
```

**With full paths:**

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Running Script with full paths"
python /home/user/projects/code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py
```

Comment: `/home/user/projects/code_sub_directory/python_code_1.py` is enough